# Add custom class to userform objects at runtime and when created from code

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out a way to initialize a userform, adding custom classes to objects that exist on the form (this part is working as expected) but after it loads and my user clicks "Add" (additional controls) I need to append the newly created controls to the class collection created at runtime.

My code is working but it's not adding the objects to the collection, so it's not firing the events when I interact with objects created from code after the userform loads.

UserForm_Initialize code:

```
Dim crtl As Control
Dim formLbEvt As fLabelClass
Dim formTbEvt As fTextBoxClass
Dim formCbEvt As fComboBoxClass
===============================
Unrelated code lives here...
===============================
Set colFormLbEvt = New Collection
Set colFormLbs = New Collection
With *userform*
    For Each crtl In .Controls
        If TypeOf crtl Is MSForms.Label Then
            Set formLbEvt = New fLabelClass
            Set formLbEvt.formLabel = crtl
            colFormLbEvt.Add formLbEvt
            colFormLbs.Add crtl, crtl.name
        End If
    Next
    Set formLbEvt = Nothing
    Set colFormTbEvt = New Collection
    Set colFormTbs = New Collection
    For Each crtl In .Controls
        If TypeOf crtl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
            Set formTbEvt = New fTextBoxClass
            Set formTbEvt.formTextBox = crtl
            colFormTbEvt.Add formTbEvt
            colFormTbs.Add crtl, crtl.name
        End If
    Next
    Set formTbEvt = Nothing
    Set colFormCbEvt = New Collection
    Set colFormCbs = New Collection
    For Each crtl In .Controls
        If TypeOf crtl Is MSForms.ComboBox Then
            Set formCbEvt = New fComboBoxClass
            Set formCbEvt.formComboBox = crtl
            colFormCbEvt.Add formCbEvt
            colFormCbs.Add crtl, crtl.name
        End If
    Next
    Set formCbEvt = Nothing
End With
===============================
Unrelated code lives here...
===============================
```

Then when a user clicks "+ Add" on the bottom of the form it adds a row of Comboboxes [I removed repeat examples] and Textboxes to the form, calling the below (which is from one of the classes added at runtime), see the **bold** sections for what should be adding the new controls to the collections:

Class module fLabelClass code:

```
Public WithEvents formLabel As MSForms.Label
Dim ctrl As Control
Dim cTag As String
Dim formLbEvt As New fLabelClass
Dim formTbEvt As New fTextBoxClass
Dim formCbEvt As New fComboBoxClass

====================================
Sub that calls addRow lives here...
====================================

Private Sub addRow(rowCount As Integer)
With *userform*
    Set ctrl = .Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "row" & rowCount + 1)
    With ctrl
        .Font.name = "Calibri"
        .Font.Size = "8"
        .Caption = rowCount + 1
        .Height = 15.75
        .Left = 6
        .SpecialEffect = 0
        .tag = rowCount + 1
        .TextAlign = 2
        .Top = 240 + (rowCount * 15.75)
        .Width = 12
        **Set formLbEvt.formLabel = ctrl
        colFormLbEvt.Add formLbEvt
        colFormLbs.Add ctrl, ctrl.name**
    End With
    Set ctrl = .Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "prodComboBox" & rowCount + 1)
    With ctrl
        .Font.name = "Calibri"
        .Font.Size = "8"
        .Height = 15.75
        .Left = 18
        .SpecialEffect = 0
        .Style = 0
        .tag = rowCount + 1
        .TextAlign = 1
        .Top = 240 + (rowCount * 15.75)
        .Width = 162
        For i = LBound(pd) To UBound(pd)
            .AddItem pd(i)
        Next i
        **Set formCbEvt.formComboBox = ctrl
        colFormCbEvt.Add formCbEvt
        colFormCbs.Add ctrl, ctrl.name**
    End With
    Set ctrl = .Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "termTextBox" & rowCount + 1)
    With ctrl
        .Font.name = "Calibri"
        .Font.Size = "8"
        .Height = 15.75
        .Left = 180
        .SpecialEffect = 0
        .tag = rowCount + 1
        .TextAlign = 2
        .Top = 240 + (rowCount * 15.75)
        .Width = 36
        **Set formTbEvt.formTextBox = ctrl
        colFormTbEvt.Add formTbEvt
        colFormTbs.Add ctrl, ctrl.name**
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

It's not throwing any errors and when I look at the collections I see the newly added items. I think I may be screwing up by declaring a new class vs. just adding the controls to the existing collections, not sure?

Comment: Think I figured it out...forgot to clear my Set (Set formLbEvt = Nothing) after each add.

Comment: You might find it easier to manage if you create a single class to manage each "row": the class would contain one "withEvents" field for each control in the row.

Comment: Thanks Tim! That would help isolate events. I qualify all the clicks by the control name so I'm making it work, will try to incorporate your idea to see if it helps performance.